# VBA how to efficiently find/vlookup in array variable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vlookup

Working on Microsoft Visual Basic Application Edition 7.1 in Excel
2013. Self-taught on VBA, before now I just struggled to get the result (I am a supply chain manager, not in a IT-related position). Now I also would like to care about efficiency issues.
Several tip lists agree on avoiding the use of Select/Activate and on reading data in large blocks. But I don't know how to search in a large block after saving it in an array variable.

The macro actually reads the list of the missing items (contained in column A of "Sheet1" of the missing item file) and divides the list on three new sheets (namely "tornio", "centro", and "acquisti" in the missing item file), based on information which are contained on both the missing file (column C of "Sheet1") and on the production chart file. Missing items reporting "Prod." on Column C will either be copied on the "tornio" or the "centro" sheets or both based on the content of the production chart file; missing items not reporting "Prod." on Column C must be copied to the "acquisti" sheet.
My inefficient code is:

```
Dim errore(1 To 10)
'create a variable to store problems (i.e. missing items which are not on the production chart file) 
Do
'start the cycle to read the missing items list which is stored in Column A
  If Cells(i, "A") <> vbNullString Then
    If Cells(i, "C") = "Prod." Then
    'based on information on the missing file, prepare for division 
         sl = Cells(i, "A")
         'store the missing item code
         Windows("cicli.xls").Activate
         'activate the production chart file
         Set d = Range("C:C").Find(sl)
         'search the missing item on the production chart file
         If Not d Is Nothing Then
         'if you find the missing item on the production chart file
            j = 1 'integer
            centro = False 'dummy
            tornio = False 'dummy
            Do
            'start the cycle to read the production chart file   
               If Cells(d.Row + j, "C") = 0 Then
               'continue as long as you find zeros (see image)
```

[image: production chart]

```
                  Select Case Left(Cells(d.Row + j, "K"), 3)
                  'based on the machine type, prepare for division
                    Case "CLO"
                       If centro = False Then
                       'if machine type is CLO then return to the missing item file and copy the current row the centro sheet  
                           centro = True
                           Windows(ma).Activate
                           Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("centro").Rows(c)
                           c = c + 1
                           Windows("cicli.xls").Activate
                       End If
                    Case "TCN", "TPA"
                    'if machine type is TCN or TPA then return to the missing item file and copy the current row the tornio sheet  
                     If tornio = False Then
                           tornio = True
                           Windows(ma).Activate
                           Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("tornio").Rows(t)
                           t = t + 1
                           Windows("cicli.xls").Activate
                       End If
                   End Select
               j = j + 1
               End If
             Loop Until Cells(d.Row + j, "C") <> 0 Or Cells(d.Row + j, "C") = vbNullString
        'close the cycle to read the production chart
            Else:
         'if you don't find the missing item on the production chart, please store the missing code 
            errore(e) = sl
            e = e + 1
         End If
    Else:
    'based on information on the missing file, prepare for division 
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("acquisti").Rows(a)
        a = a + 1
    End If
End If
Windows(ma).Activate
'return on the missing list 
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
i = i + 1
Loop Until Cells(i, "B") = vbNullString
'close the cycle to read the missing items list
```

Now suppose that I save the production chart on an array variable

```
   Dim cicli as Variant
   Windows("cicli.xls").Activate
   cicli = Union(Columns("C:C"), Columns("K:K")).Value
```

How can I make the above search for the missing items on such array variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that the following one is the best strategy to achieve efficiency, but a qualitative measure suggests that the time it takes the macro to run have been reduced by approximately 44%

```
Workbooks.Open (laura & "pianificazione produzione\cicli.xls")
Set ci = Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row, "C"))
Set ka = Range(Cells(1, "K"), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row, "K"))
```

then start the Do cycle

```
Dim errore(1 To 10)
If Cells(i, "A") <> vbNullString Then
If Cells(i, "C") = "Prod." Then
     sl = Cells(i, "A")
     Set d = ci.Find(sl)
     'now search on saved range ci rather than on production chart file
     If Not d Is Nothing Then
        j = 1 'integer
        centro = False 'dummy
        tornio = False 'dummy
        Do
           If ci(d.Row + j, 1) = 0 Then
           'now continue on saved range ci rather than on production chart file
               Select Case Left(ka(d.Row + j, 1), 3)
```

[...] and then continues